# In this script, what does return True do?

Tags: python

In this script, what does "return True" do?

```
def bigger(first, second):
  print max(first, second)
  return True
```

Comment: it returns True to whatever expression called the function

Comment: Do you not think it returns `True` from the function?

Comment: Without context there's no way to determine the use case for returning True from this function.

Comment: Also, based on the `print` syntax, this is Python 2, which was sunsetted completely two years ago and was de facto legacy long before that. Basically, this code was written by our ancestors.

Answer (score 1):

True is a [boolean](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_booleans.asp) value.

Your function, Bigger, is a function that receives two arguments. It's probably supposed to check if the first is bigger than the second - it currently doesn't do that. The function will [return](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) `True`, passing that value to whoever called it.

As for how boolean values (true and false) are used - one way is in [conditions](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_conditions.asp) (if statements). True meaning the condition will happen, false meaning it wont. e.g.

```
# 2>1 evaluates to True
if(2>1):
    print('2 is bigger than 1')
```

will print the statement below, while this won't:

```
# 1>2 evaluates to False
if(1>2):
    # This line won't be executed, because the condition isn't satisfied.
    print('1 is bigger than 2')
```

That means if you [call your function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) like so, the line will print, because it returns `True`.

```
if(bigger(2,1)):
    print('2 is bigger than 1')
```

Comment: I think if you remove parentheses in `if` head, it get more pythonic

Comment: @MoRe Quick dumb question - does that work in Python2 as well?

Comment: yes, it is a keyword like `print`